# Django Теги Циклы

Tags: python, django

как подать в шаблон этот список и пройтись по нему циклом?

```
def index(request):

# Доступные тарифные планы
plans = [
    {
        "name": "Бесплатно",
        "price": "0",
        "options": {"users": 10, "space": 10, "support": "Почтовая рассылка"},
    },
    {
        "name": "Профессиональный",
        "price": "49",
        "options": {"users": 50, "space": 100, "support": "Телефон и email"},
    },
    {
        "name": "Корпоративный",
        "price": "99",
        "options": {"users": 100, "space": 500, "support": "Персональный менеджер"},
    },
]

return render(request, 'index.html', context={'items':plans})
```

Не получается в шаблоне настроить цикл `{% for %}`. Нужно чтобы в цикле сводилось name, price, options в зависимости от счётчика цикла. Например, есть такой index.html:

```
<body>
    <div
      class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm"
    >
      <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal">Всяческие услуги</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4">Тарифы</h1>
      <p class="lead">
        Ознакомьтесь с нашими тарифами и закажите услугу.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Бесплатно</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">
              $0 <small class="text-muted">/ в месяц</small>
            </h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>10 пользователей</li>
              <li>10 GB места</li>
              <li>Поддержка: Почтовая рассылка</li>
            </ul>
            <a
              href="mailto:order@company.site?subject=Услуга Бесплатно"
              class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"
            >
              Связаться
          </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer class="pt-4 my-md-5 pt-md-5 border-top">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md">
            Всяческие услуги
            <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 3020</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Нужно , чтобы вместо бесплатно, 0$, 10 пользователей, 10гб места, поддержка выводились значения из списка соответственно и было 3 колонки таких. Пробовал заключить эту часть в for и что только не перебрал , всё равно не получается((объясните пожалуйста,  буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

передай plains в контекст шаблона и потом простой цикл

```
{% for plain in plains %}
    {{ plain.name }}
    {{ plain.price }}
    {{ plain.options.users }}
    {{ plain.options.space }}
    {{ plain.options.support }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: В шаблон нельзя подать список, только словарь

Comment: О да, я смог, context={'items':plans} помог, спасибо